# Произведение отличных от нуля чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая считывает 10 чисел и выводит произведение отличных от нуля чисел.

**Формат входных данных:**
На вход программе подаются 10 целых чисел, каждое на отдельной строке.

**Формат выходных данных:**
Программа должна вывести произведение отличных от нуля чисел.

**Примечание:** Гарантируется, что хотя бы одно из 10 чисел является ненулевым.

```
Sample Input 1:

8 
0  
1  
2  
1  
0  
0  
5  
4  
12


Sample Output 1:

3840
```

Мой код:

```
total = 1
a = int(input())
for i in range(1, 10):
    if a != 0 and a *= a:
        a += a
print(total)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
result = 1
for _ in range(10):
    a = int(input())
    if a:
        result *= a
print(result)
```

Comment: Дьякую!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @gipotezaizgaza Будьласка ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Формат входных данных На вход программе подаются 10 целых чисел,
> каждое на отдельной строке.

однако вы приводите пример

```
Sample Input 1:

8 0 1 2 1 0 0 5 4 12
```

т.е. ввод всех чисел в одной строке

так как именно надо ввести то?

касательно вашего кода - перед тем как задавать вопрос вы бы сами прошлись по нему и ответили на вопрос - а что делает каждая строчка вашего кода

```
    total = 1
a = int(input()) # ввели одно число
for i in range(1, 10): # в цикле непонятно что сделали
    if a != 0 and a *= a: # что это за условие?
        a += a
print(total)
```

если уж на то пошло (в связи с новым годом)

```
res = 1
for num in map(int, input().split()):
    if num != 0:
        res *= num
```

можно и в одну строчку, но придется библиотеку тащить:

```
import functools
res = functools.reduce(lambda res, num: num * res, [i for i in map(int, input().split()) if i != 0])
```

Comment: Благодарю вам всем !!! я уже 3 недели мучаюсь с этой задачой(((

Comment: а что с ней мучаться то? разложите ее на куски и отдельно по кускам делайте, т.е. разложите на самые простые подзадачи

Comment: я изучаю соло и порой очень сложно без ментора

Comment: поправил Sample Input

Comment: когда решаете задачу в начале изучения языка удобно самому быть компьютером - т.е. алгоритм писать на бумаге и пытаться его в голове выполнить как выполнил бы компьютер - вот в вашем алгоритме было бы так 1) ввожу переменную `total` и записываю в нее `1` 2) получают от пользователя строку `input()`, перевожу ее в целое число `int(input())` и записываю в переменную `a` 3) запускаю цикл от 1 до 10 3.1) индекс цикла `i` равен 1 3.2) если переменная `а ` не ровна 0 (проверяю - не ровна) и если ААААА непонятная запись, не вижу условия, ОШИБКА. Т.е. вначале сами будьте компьютером

Answer (score 2):

вот немного изменённая версия вашего кода:

```
total = 1
for i in range(10):
    a = int(input())
    if a != 0:
        total *= a
print(total)
```

если ввод должен быть в одной строке, то так:

```
total = 1
for a in map(int, input().split()):
    if a != 0:
        total *= a
print(total)
```

также можно попробовать так:

```
total = 1
for a in map(int, input().split()):
    total *= a or 1
print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

Если число n подаваемое на вход равно нулю, то в скобках при верном равенстве будет значение True==1, в таком случае имеющее произведение домножается не на 0, а на  0 + 1. Если же число n подаваемое на вход не равно нулю, то в скобках значение False==0, следовательно произведение домножается на n + 0.

```
total = 1
for _ in range(10):
    n = int(input())
    total *= n + (n == 0)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner

Читаем целые из входного потока по одному на строку. `stdin` притворяется `iterable`, который выдаёт строки по одной. `map` превращает строки в числа применяя `int`:

```
g1 = map(int, stdin)
```

Отбрасываем нули. Круглые скобки - генератор:

```
g2 = (v for v in g1 if v != 0)
```

[reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) - классика функционального программирования: берёт функцию с двумя аргументами и последовательно применяет её к элементам и промежуточному итогу. `mul` - произведение двух чисел. `1` - начальное значение.

```
p = reduce(mul, g2, 1)
```

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 4]
> <промежуточный итог> * <число из списка> -> <новый промежуточный итог>
> 1 * 1 -> 1
> 1 * 2 -> 2
> 2 * 3 -> 6
> 6 * 4 -> 24
> ```

Результат печатаем:

```
print(p)
```

Всё вместе:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
from sys import stdin

print(reduce(mul, (v for v in map(int, stdin) if v != 0), 1))
```

> ```
> $ python product.py
> 8
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 5
> 4
> 12
> Ctrl+D
> 3840
> ```

Answer (score 0):

считывать надо в теле цикла! И вам надо умножать переменную-счетчик на a (в случае, если условие в if выполняется). Прибавлять единицу к счетчику не надо. Мы же не количество считаем...